# Insert php variable in a href not working in second insert

Tags: php

I'm trying to use this:

```
<a href='intrebare/lul.php?title=".&hmm."'>
```

and I have the `$hmm` variable from a previous reference

```
 <a href='article.php?title=".$row['a_title']."&date=".$row['a_dat']."&hmm=".$row['a_id']."'>
```

but something isn't working.
I can see `hmm=1` in the link, but when I open the secondary page the variable is not in link, it's only:

```
lul.php?title=%22.&hmm.%22
```

Comment: you should research string concatenation

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs u mean to search again in the database ?

Comment: Everything is working as expected. `&hmm` is not a variable.

Comment: @kerbholz and how should i do it ?

Comment: Do you mean `echo "<a href='intrebare/lul.php?title=".$hmm."'>";` ?

Comment: @MatrixCow08 no it's a reference to another page

Comment: @ValentinGrigorean I think you've to edit the question and make it more simpler to understand, also post your full code.

Comment: @ValentinGrigorean no, I mean string concatenation ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *interpolate* your PHP code into template strings. Double quotes `"` don't do that: curly braces do.

So your 'a' tag in your template should look like this:

```
<a href='intrebare/lul.php?title={$hmm}'>
```

(By the way I think you mistyped the variable reference with a `&` instead of `$`.)